"x" is not a constructor- PlayWright automating testing beginner
I am learning Playwright. This is what I have so far. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? I referred to youtube videos and still unable to see what the mistake is. I appreciate your help!
This is the LoginPage.js
class LoginPage{

    constructor(page){
        this.page=page;
        this.loginInput = 'input[name="username"]';
        this.passwordInput = 'input[name="password"]';
        this.loginButton = '.MuiLoadingButton-root';
    }

    //method

    async logintoWorld(){
        await this.page.fill(this.username, "manager1");
        await this.page.fill(this.password, "myPassword");
        await this.page.click(this.loginButton);
    }
}

export default LoginPage; 

This is the login.spec.js
import {test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/LoginPage';


test('Login to testingworld', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://mytestingworld.com/auth/login');
  const myLogin = new LoginPage(page);
  await myLogin.logintoWorld();
});

When I run the test, I get this error:
@
login.spec.js:7
TypeError: _LoginPage.LoginPage is not a constructor



Use import LoginPage from '../pages/LoginPage'; since it's the default export. See this answer.

Thankyou that worked! Now I am getting another error though: page.fill:selector: expected string, got undefined. Also, I wasn't aware of the difference between importing { } vs the other import from. So I searched up on it and found amazing explanation for it on stack overflow! So thankyou for the correction, I learned something new!

No problem! Can you update the code to show the new error? If it's the same as this, then make sure this.username and this.password are defined somehow. Did you mean this.loginInput? Thanks.

This error is fixed by changing
export default LoginPage;

to
export { LoginPage };

Alternatively, you can use the other way around. If you want to leave your export default LoginPage, you have to change your import like this:
import LoginPage from '../pages/LoginPage';

That's all.
